# SoftLayer API : How to get NetScaler list in Softlayer

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am developing a cloud portal using SoftLayer java client Lib.
Regarding N/W part, I'm looking for API that can retrieve the list of load balance.

I succeeded to do it through,

```
SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_Service
/[Service_id]/getObject?objectMask=status
-425437/getObject?objectMask=object
```

with service ID from

```
SoftLayer_Account/getAdcLoadBalancers? 
objectMask=adcLoadBalancers.virtualServers.serviceGroups.services.id
```

However I couldn't only retrieve the list of LB that only regarding global LB or LB appliance, Netscaler VPX.

The question is, 
How can I get the list only for local/global/Netscaler per each?

Answer (score 2):

These API requests can help you:

To get Global balancing list:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getGlobalLoadBalancerAccounts
Method: GET
```

To get local balancing list, execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getAdcLoadBalancers?objectMask=mask[loadBalancerHardware[datacenter],ipAddress] 
Method: GET
```

To get NetScaler list:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getApplicationDeliveryControllers
Method: GET
```

To get Network Gateway Appliance (Vyatta):

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkGateways

Method: GET
```

**References:**
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getGlobalLoadBalancerAccounts
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getAdcLoadBalancers
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getApplicationDeliveryControllers
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkGateways

Regards.