# Is there a way to get a SoftLayer account's virtual load balancers?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

[image]I have tried all methods listed in the answer here: [SoftLayer API : How to get NetScaler list in Softlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35031725)
and only ever get back the physical load balancers on our account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

UPDATED:

Currently the portal requires to use another service different to SoftLayer_Account to display **IBM Bluemix** Load Balancers as shown in the portal's LB list, the proper service and method is SoftLayer_Network_LBaaS_LoadBalancer::getAllObjects.

Try the following REST request:

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_LBaaS_LoadBalancer/getAllObjects
```

---

---

To retrieve other type of load balancer the request should make use of Object Masks, this will include the proper parameters you require in the response, for example in this case physical load balancer is on loadBalancerHardware property but virtual details you require, are on ipAddress object.

Try the following REST request:

```
http://[username]:[apiKey]@stable.application.qadal0501.softlayer.local/v3.1/sldn/rest/SoftLayer_Account/getAdcLoadBalancers?objectMask=mask[id, accountId, loadBalancerHardware[hostname, id, fullyQualifiedDomainName], ipAddress[ipAddress, id]]
```

Currently the portal displays Local and Global Load balancers, the request above works with getAdcLoadBalancers method to retrieve Local Load Balancers, for Global you should use SoftLayer_Account:getGlobalLoadBalancerAccounts

For more information I recommend the following:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks

Comment: tried 
_https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getAdcLoadBalancers?objectMask=mask[id,accountId,loadBalancerHardware[hostname,id,fullyQualifiedDomainName],ipAddress[ipAddress,id]]_ 
and still got back an empty array. As I said in the question, I need to access my account's local **virtual** load balancer

Comment: How did you created those virtual load balancers?, currently the portal displays only Local/Global load balancers, could you point out the url or where are you seeing these "Virtual" and Physical load balancers information in the Portal?.

Comment: Sure, and thanks for helping! https://control.softlayer.com/network/loadbalancing/cloud . I go to Network->Load_Balancing->Local. We created using the portal. I will add image to op.

Comment: Hello, I´ve updated the Answer with another rest request, try this and let me know if it solved your problem.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!!